# How to make this array assignment work in php5.6?

Tags: arrays, php-7, php-5.6

I have a part of code, that was written in php7:

```
[$columns, $values, $conditions] = $this->gatherConditions($identifier);
```

where `$identifier` is an array. When I run this code on php5.6 server it shows error - `unexpected "=" on line X`. How this line should be written for working in php 5.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent in PHP before the short-array syntax list-destructuring was allowed in PHP 7.1, is

`list($columns, $values, $conditions) = $this->gatherConditions($identifier);`

See the php.net/list page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php